# Perl having problem in programme execution

Tags: linux, scripting, perl, programming

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
#Script:name2.pl - Demonstrates use of chop
#
print("Enter your name:");
$name=<STDIN>;
$lname = chop($name);                      #Removes newline character from $name
if ($lname ne "") {
   print("$lname,have a nice day\n");
 } else {
 print("You have not entered your name\n");
}
```

```
$ ./name2.pl
Enter your name:stallman

,have a nice day
$
```

While executing a Perl program, it is not executing the "chop" function.

Is there any error in the programming line?

Answer (score 1):

See [chop](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop)

> Chops off the last character of a string and returns the character chopped.

I.e. it modifies the string in-place.

You assume that it returns the "chopped string".

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $x = "Turing, Alana";

my $r = chop($x);

print "\$x is now '$x', and \$r is now '$r'\n";
```

Then:

```
$x is now 'Turing, Alan', and $r is now 'a'
```

Comment: Actual example, 1) $name=<STDIN>; chop($name) ; will remove the last line entered with Enter and 2)chop($name=<STDIN>); and 3)$lname=chop($name); are option to 1)   as per book.but is showing different result

Comment: I can't read your picture, but if there's a `chop` you should almost certainly be using `chomp` instead

Comment: No it's chop($name) is executing but $lname = chop($name) is showing different result is the problem.tutorial tells its $lname = chop($name) is option to chop($name)

Comment: @ShridharBWaghamare I don't know what the tutorial says but what counts is what Perl actually does. I added an example.

Comment: @ShridharBWaghamare You want `chomp($name)` and then use `$name`.  You almost never use `chop()` in Perl programming.  Further queries about this should probably go to the StackOverflow site, as Perl language questions are off topic here (it's not Unix-specific).